# Assigning a value to a dynamic type using reflection and bypassing the object cast\box that GetValue returns

Tags: c#, dynamic, reflection, casting

I have two objects that have exactly the same properties. Here's an example:

```
public class Field<T>
{
   public T Value {get;set;}
   // more things
}

public class MainObject
{
   public string MyStr {get;set;}
   public int? MyInt {get;set;}
   public bool? MyBool {get;set;}
}

public class MainObjectField
{
   public Field<string> MyStr {get;set;}
   public Field<int?> MyInt {get;set;}
   public Field<bool?> MyBool {get;set;}
}
```

I have a task to create an instance of `MainObjectField` based on xpath instructions that I get from an external source.
I need to fetch the `Value` from the `MainObject`'s instance as a part of the task.

Since I don't know about the type of the current property in compile type, I'm using a dynamic variable.

Here's a short example (this is **NOT** how the code looks like in real life - this example if to simplify the post):

```
MainObject obj = new MainObject
{
    MyBool = true,
    MyInt = 12,
    MyStr = "Example"
};

MainObjectField fieldObj = new MainObjectField();
var myBool = obj.GetType().GetProperty("MyBool").GetValue(obj);
var myInt = obj.GetType().GetProperty("MyInt").GetValue(obj);
var myStr = obj.GetType().GetProperty("MyStr").GetValue(obj);

dynamic fieldBool = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Field<bool?>));
dynamic fieldInt = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Field<int?>));
dynamic fieldString = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Field<string>));

fieldBool.Value = myBool; // exception
fieldInt.Value = myInt; // exception
fieldString.Value = myStr; // exception 

fieldObj.MyBool = fieldBool;
fieldObj.MyInt = fieldInt;
fieldObj.MyStr = fieldString;
```

Now I'm getting this exception:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'bool?'. An explicit
>   conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

I understand why I'm getting the exception and I'm trying to find a workaround.

I know that the `currentField.Value` and the `val` value are suppose to be the same type.

My problem is that using reflection (`GetValue` returns an `object`) automatically casts\boxes the value into an `object` and ruins my plans.
I can't cast to the "correct" value since I know the types only in runtime.

How can I work this around?

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going on with so much code missing. It would be much easier to help you if you provided a short but complete example demonstrating the problem.

Comment: This code is telling you that a type of "object" is not a type of bool... object val = GetValFromMainObject(); // using reflection
currentField.Value = val; // I get an exception here...   If you know it's to be a bool just cast it.  If you don't know ahead of time what it needs to be then you can use this type of code... var val.gettypename = pe().underlyingsystemtype.name

Comment: @JonSkeet - I've edited and added a simple piece of code example. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the binder will use the *static* type of the value you're trying to assign to the property - whereas you want to do this dynamically. All you need to do is change the variables to be of type `dynamic` and it works:

```
dynamic myBool = obj.GetType().GetProperty("MyBool").GetValue(obj);
dynamic myInt = obj.GetType().GetProperty("MyInt").GetValue(obj);
dynamic myStr = obj.GetType().GetProperty("MyStr").GetValue(obj);
```

Basically, dynamic typing will work dynamically with any expressions with a compile-time type of `dynamic`, but will use the compile-time type of any *other* expressions when performing that binding.

Comment: I can't believe that I didn't think about doing that. Thank you for you help!!

Comment: @AmirPopovich: Don't beat yourself up about it - there are *lots* of subtleties when it comes to dynamic typing. This would have been more obvious if you were just calling a method and passing the value as an argument - which is what the property assignment *effectively* is, of course...